# Adding urgent priority to mail set from mailto link

Tags: email, mailto

I want to add a mailto link on our web page. I want to add a urgent priority to this mail.

Comment: You want to encode the priority in the link directly? I do not think this is possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

mailto links just doesn't support this feature , sorry.

however, you could use a specific subject and filter it in your inbox

```
<a href="mailto:webmaster@website.com?subject=Urgent">Send a email</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get your priority, but probably not that way.

Most mail clients honor `subject=` and `body=` in the query string of a `mailto:` link. Some mail clients treat multiple `body=` attributes as different lines; others only use the last `body`. Getting to your point, though: **I don't think most clients will let you set priority**, and it only takes *one* client that won't do it to make your system unreliable.

The easiest approach is to **use mail filters to set priority on inbound mail**. The filters should set the priority based on the subject lines, which you *can* reliably control.

If your mail system's filters can't set priority, try sorting to different mail folders.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this with a mailto: link, but you could create a server-side contact form that sends the e-mail out with the proper headers.

Answer (score 1):

I guess if such a feature exist it's browser-specific.

[from w3's website:](http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970917/htmlweb.html)

> User agents may support MAILTO URL
>   extensions that are not yet Internet
>   standards (e.g., appending subject
>   information to a URL with the syntax
>   "?Subject=my%20subject" where any
>   space characters are replaced by
>   "%20"). Some user agents also support
>   "?Cc=email-address".

Comment: you can append all of those things but there is no support for priority

Answer (score 1):

It can't be done.